# Windows Server 2012 Proxy Setting Using Group Policy

Tags: windows, group-policy, proxy

I want to set proxy for all users in local windows server 2012 by using local group policy?
My windows is not a domain controller.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit this settings with Group Policy Editor because [Microsoft deleted it](https://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/ie-policy/warning-installing-ie-10-on-your-windows-7-workstation-removes-ie-maintenance-policy-from-group-policy/).

But you can try configure the registry `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`. Nice guide in [this msdn blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askie/2015/10/12/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-for-ie10-and-ie11-as-iem-is-not-available/). Your case after words:

> 2) The alternative way of configuring the Proxy Setting is deploying
>   the registries keys directly.

Comment: But it doesn't work for me, i have citrix xenapp on this server and when users connect to xennapp an lunch a browser, the proxy doesn't work by this solution